# Service layer classes in ASP.NET MVC application best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-mvc-4

Can you provide a code sample with basic architecture guidlines for creating service layer classes (which supposed to be consumed by web front-ends, web api etc.)?

Do you think this is a good tutorial? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

Comment: Doesn't matter that you are using MVC 4. It works the same with MVC 3 and MVC 2. The same goes for EF. Just use Google, there are hundreds of threads on this subject here at StackOverflow.

Comment: @Lean, yeah there are hundreds of shitty code samples on this subject :) for example, when people without any good reason implement custom repository and unit of work patterns over EF DbContext which already implements these two patterns.

Answer (score 4):

I personally don't like how that article describes passing errors from a service layer back to the controller (with IValidationDictionary), I would make it work more like this instead:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMembershipService membershipService;

    // service initialization is handled by IoC container
    public AccountController(IMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        this.membershipService = membershipService;
    }

    // .. some other stuff ..

    [AllowAnonymous, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (this.ModelSteate.IsValid)
        {
            var result = this.membershipService.CreateUser(
                model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, isApproved: true
            );

            if (result.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(
                    model.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false
                );

                return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            result.Errors.CopyTo(this.ModelState);
        }

        return this.View();
    }
}
```

Or.. as mikalai mentioned, make the service throw validation exceptions, catch them in a global filter and insert into model state.

Comment: Or, probably it could make less coding, if service throws exception on error which are handled using filter.